# Javascript not working in loaded DIV using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load a part of a page inside a Div on my frontpage using .load. My problem is that the loaded content have a set if buttons with javascript inside them, and they wont execute and it goes to the systemä Im usings errorpage.

The buttons have the same script but different ids, name and classes and looks like this:

```
<a href="" trg="" name="_ec_oie4" id="_ec_oie4" class="action actionbasket cancel" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;">Cancel</a>
```

I have tried multiple ways to load the content without any luck. If I load the whole page it works aside from all the other problems that gives.

Example of scripts I have tried:

Script 1:

```
$(".dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu").load("/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox, script”);
```

Script 2:

```
$('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox, script', function () {
    $.getScript('urltomyscript'); //the script that handles the buttons, as far as I can see
});
```

Script 3:

```
$(function(){
    $.get('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket', function(result){
        $result = $(result);
        $result.find('#centerbox.itembox.centerbox').appendTo('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu');
        $result.find('scripts').appendTo('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu');
    }, 'html');
});
```

Script 4:

```
$('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox', function() {
    $("#_ec_oie2").on("click", function() {
        if (UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click')) { }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Nothing works. They all load the content but the buttons won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because your inline script does not execute since the element is loaded dynamically..

Comment: Yeah I have no clue on how to get them executed corretcly.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the script 4 to:

```
 $('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox,script'); //Load the content
```

i'm not 100% sure that this will load the script also.

and for dynamic content you have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on("click","#_ec_oie2",function(){
  if (UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click')){

  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. Unfortunaly this gives me the same result.

Comment: My system goes to an /error page when I click the button . looking at firebugs logs all I can see is: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: can you try to locate the scritp with UI.pb_boolean function into a single file and try to load it with $.getScript("pathScript")

Comment: I tried this with script#2 and that didnt work either.

Comment: @TiGres The div im loading my content in is present at the page im loading the html from - on that page it works, so must be a script not loading?

Comment: @user3344734 `.load()` loads also the JS, I will investigate about this because I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the problem occurs due to load being executed async, and the HTML therefore is updated AFTER the script that makes the buttons work have executed.

The simple way to solve it, is firing the button script in a callback:

```
$(".dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu").load("/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox, script”, function(){//this get executed, when content has loaded});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. Unfortunaly this gives me the same result.